# Algorithm for closing a polygon with two edges along a screen texture edge

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, graph-algorithm

What is the best algorithm for closing a polygon with two edges along the edge of a screen texture?

To illustrate my point please consider this case:

[image]

A user starts drawing a polygon by drawing a line between points `A` and `B`, and then between `B` and `C`. These points are on a screen texture grid that is delimited by the rectangle shown with black edges in the figure above.

The program then should be smart enough to automatically close the polygon, which in this simple case is a rectangle, by pathfinding point `D` and add it to an array containing its vertices. This is an edge case of pathfinding via a variant of the A* algorithm that I'm using, because this algorithm will try to backtrack from `C`, to `B` and then to `A`, which is not what I want.

I tried to make a rule in the data source of the pathfinder algorithm so that it cannot backtrack. However, a simple rule of not drawing to the left does not allow the pathfinder to close the polygon when it tries to draw the edge from `D` to `A`.

I thought about to determine whether the polygon is clockwise or counterclockwise but it is not clear to me what rule I should use to force the pathfinder to find point `D` and not backtrack to point `B`.

Is there a simple algorithm for this edge case? The algorithm should be strong enough to handle all polygons, which are always drawn with straight horizontal or vertical lines.

Comment: I don't quite see the difference to the same thing not on screen borders (at least if you don't allow off-screen points.)

Comment: Point D, even though is on the edge of the screen, is definitely an on-screen point, where the user is allowed to draw.

Comment: For arbitrary polygons, how would your algorithm know the user doesn't want to draw a triangle ABC, then?

Comment: I edited my question to make my point clearer... Because only horizontal and vertical lines are allowed.

Comment: Ah. That was a non-trivial omission, then. But I still can't see the point why you seem to be looking at screen borders. There's no difference if the same thing happens to the left or top.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought when I mentioned "straight" lines that would be obvious, but of course a line at an angle is also a "straight" line. I'm sorry I don't understand when you say "there's no difference if the same thing happens to the left or top". I need to close the polygon in order to fill that in and the pathfinder always looks at the smallest polygon that can be made implicitly. Is that what you are asking?